# System.IO.Compression.ZipFile UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, zip

I'm trying to backup some files using the .NET 4.5 ZipFile class and the CreateFromDirectory(string, string) method.  I'm getting an UnauthorizedAccessException - Access Denied.  I can successfully read all files in that directory as well as write a file to that directory.  So I would think that the permissions are set up properly.  Any thoughts on why I'm getting access denied on the ZipFile class?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string backupLocation = @"C:\Backups";
    string directoriesToBackup = @"F:\myMedia\myPictures\Our Family\2012\Misc";

    try
    {
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(directoriesToBackup, backupLocation);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\myMedia\myPictures\Our Family\2012\Misc");
    File.Create(@"F:\myMedia\myPictures\Our Family\2012\Misc\testCreateFromVs.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo i in di.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It seems you have misunderstood something.**

```
backupLocation = @"C:\Backups";
```

you want to overwrite the **directory** "C:\Backups" with a **file** ! That's not allowed! ;-) (Access Denied)

You have to specify the path with file name.
**Syntax: CreateFromDirectory(string,string)**

```
public static void CreateFromDirectory(
    string sourceDirectoryName,
    string destinationArchiveFileName
)
```

Example:

```
 string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
 string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
 [...]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I can't believe I overlooked that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: that can happen in the rush ever ;-)

Comment: Funny, got the exact same error for the exact same reason... So if it can comfort you, you're not alone my friend :-D

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to create the target directory before I started to zip the file there, but was creating the target directory as the name of the zip file, so because the empty zip file already existed (as a directory), I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can also arises when a folder with the same name as the (output) zip already exists

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with Unity and I had manually added System.IO.Compression.dll and System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll (and relevant XMLs) into Assets folder.

But I chose a DLL with wrong SDK version, and while it worked fine on MacOs, it gave UnauthorizedAccessException in Android and iOS.

I solved the issue by removing dll's and XML's and following the thread on [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-compression-zip-missing.577492/page-2) .

Basically you have to make sure your project Api Compatibility Level and dll .Net version matches.